# No component factory found for [object Object]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a modal for my Ionic project, but when I run it and click on the button that activates `presentEventModal()`, I get the error in the title.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventModalPage } from '../event-modal/event-modal';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  currentEvent;
  events = [];
  today = new Date();

  constructor (
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
              this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
              this.alertCtrl = alertCtrl;
              this.modalCtrl = modalCtrl;
    }

  onChange($event) {
    console.log($event);
    this.currentEvent = $event;
  }

  async presentEventModal() {
    const eventModal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: EventModalPage
    });
    return await eventModal.present();
  }

  createEvent(date, title, duration) {
    return {
      date: date,
      title: title,
      duration: duration,
    }
  }
}
```

I've seen similar errors posted, but this one says `[object Object]`, so I don't know what the problem is. Here is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { CalendarModule } from 'ion2-calendar'
import { EventModalPage } from '../pages/event-modal/event-modal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    EventModalPage,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    CalendarModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    EventModalPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm running Ionic 3.20.0 if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add EventModalPage component to the entryComponents section in your module

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue. I updated the code in the original post to match what I have now.

Answer (score 1):

import `EventModalPage` in your `app.module.ts` and add it to `entryComponents: []`

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue. I updated the code in the original post to match what I have now.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your `app.module.ts`. The only thing I can see is the order is a bit different to the default setup, but I'm not sure that should matter. The default order is `declarations`, `entryComponents`, `imports`, `providers`, `bootstrap`.